# Limiting mobile data usage by application

Tags: android, data

There's a game on my Android device that uses up quite a bit of data even though I checked the "Restrict background data" box for the application in the Mobile data panel. I've also ensured that I close the application properly by swiping it off the app switcher screen (or hitting clear all).

I'm looking for an application that allows me to **restrict all data for specific applications**. The only time I would be playing the game would be on a Wi-Fi connection, so it shouldn't use any data at all. A nice feature would be to limit the amount of data the app can use according to the billing cycle set in the device instead of cutting it off completely but that's optional.

Right now I've resorted to completely turning off mobile data and intermittently re-enabling it to check social media or whatever else that requires Internet connectivity, but it's not an ideal method as I'd like to leave data enabled to receive notifications and email more quickly when I'm away from Wi-Fi areas.

I am running Android 5.1 on an unrooted LG G4.

I've already looked at these questions:

- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117350/disable-all-but-a-few-applications-from-accessing-mobile-data-connections
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86563/how-to-control-monitor-and-limit-bandwidth-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you a *single* recommendation here, as I have nothing *completely* fitting your requirements. But there are several approaches you could take, each requiring a specialized app:

1. Using an automation app to turn-off mobile data whenever you start that app
2. Using a firewall to forbid the app access to mobile data

### Using an automation app to turn-off mobile data whenever you start that app

This of course has the disadvantage of mobile data being unavailable to all other apps as well, as long as this one app is running in foreground. With Android 5.1, I'm not sure whether it requires root access – as with each new Android version, one of those toggles gets out of reach of apps to switch (e.g. switching to airplane mode will require root with Lollipop).

I'm using **[Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info)** for all kind of automation. *Tasker* combines "conditions" and "tasks" (actions) to "profiles", so your profile here would be:

- **Condition:** *Application* (pick your app)
- **Task:** *Net › Mobile Data* Off

With that, whenever your app-in-question comes to foreground (usually when you open it / use it actively), mobile data would be switched off.

### Using a firewall to forbid the app access to mobile data

There are several [firewall apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall) available for Android. Most of them require root access. Using one of those has a big pro for you: only the app(s) you want to prevent from using mobile data would be affected. As all my devices are rooted, I've never used one of the (limited) no-root firewall apps, so I cannot give a clear recommendation here. **[Mobiwol](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall)** has a pretty good standing here (4.1 stars at 5k+ votes), and seems to fit your requirements:

- **restrict all data for specific applications:** Yes. Separately for background/foreground data, and separately for mobile/WiFi
- **no root:** the full app name ("Mobiwol: NoRoot Firewall") claims such :)

[image: Mobiwol] [image: Mobiwol]
<sup>*Mobiwol* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall); click images for larger variants)</sup>